# How to get historic trending hashtags on twitter by date and/or by location

Tags: twitter

For a project I want to know what was the top trending #hashtags on twitter on a particular date.

For example following are 2 sample use cases :-

1. What was the most (or top 3) trending twitter #hashtag(s) on 21/11/2011 for US location.
2. What was the most (or top 3) trending twitter #hashtag(s) on 21/11/2011.

Any idea how to get it?

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755110/twitter-streaming-get-trends-on-twitter-on-the-basis-of-countries/29760363#29760363