# Twitter Streaming: Get trends on Twitter on the basis of countries

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I am using `tweepy` to get twitter tweets. I want to get the current trends based on the country of my choice. My code is as follows:

```
import tweepy
file = open("data.txt", 'r')
authentication = tweepy.OAuthHandler('consumer_key', 'consumer_secret')
authentication.set_access_token('access_token', 'access_secret')
api = tweepy.API(authentication)
trends = api.trends_available()
for trend in trends:
    print trend
```

The code above gives me a list of countries. I want to use the list to check the current trends in the country. How do I extract the trending `hashtags` for these countries?

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071890/how-to-get-historic-trending-hashtags-on-twitter-by-date-and-or-by-location) question but it has no answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the wrong endpoint for this job you have to use [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place) which translates to tweepy `api.trends_place(woeid)` and provide an `woeid` as described in this page which you can get also from `api.trends_available()` results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Worked wonderfully. I also wanted to ask, is there anyway I can get the number of tweets for a particular trend? I know the number of tweets will keep on increasing rapidly, but fr that instant in time, the number of tweets? Is it possible?

Comment: No thats not directly possible :-( 
May be you can use the search end point and get your own counts but thats a little complicated

Comment: Any documentation that I can refer to?

Comment: how to stream this in realtime?